# How can i show the total number of staff in each offices that both stored in my database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Okay so in my website I have shown my two tables which are Office Table and Staff Table together so it looks like this

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQCna.png)

Now i am trying to also show the total number of Staffs and I am struggling to do it. 
This is my query for the the Office and Staff table. How and What can i add to also show the total number of staff in each office?

```
SELECT * FROM offices           
JOIN staffs             
ON offices.office_id = staffs.st_office_id;
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: use _COUNT_ and _GROUP BY_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be look as:

```
select 
  a.office_name, 
  (select count(*) from staffs b where b.st_office_id = a.office_id)
from offices a
```

Comment: Or you can use "group by" statment

Comment: subqueries don't typically perform as well as group by given that the database optimizing engine can't optimize the subqueries as well.

Comment: Great! But consider the post of Roger Cracel. It matters. So, use GROUP BY, it would be best way.

Answer (score 1):

So you have two table: offices and staffs and you want to count all staff across all offices?

```
SELECT COUNT( 1 )
  FROM offices
  JOIN staffs ON( offices.office_id = staffs.office_id );
```

If you want the count per office, you can:

```
SELECT offices.office_id, offices.name, COUNT( 1 )
  FROM offices
  JOIN staffs ON( offices.office_id = staffs.office_id )
 GROUP BY offices.office_id, offices.name;
```

Hope this helps!